# db2: correlate tablespace file to database object

Tags: db2

Using DB2 v9.7 (windows), with an SMS tablespace. 
Inside the tablespace folder are files for the various db objects. 
Ex) SQL00003.IN1, SQL00003.DAT, etc..

How do I determine which database object corresponds to which file? 
(for both indexes and tables)

Comment: The `db2dart` report for the tablespace might contain this information. Out of curiosity, why do you need it?

Comment: The sizes of the files do not seem to jive with estimated index and table sizes from the syscat schema tables. I'm trying to reclaim some disk space. Planning to run some REORG commands and it would be handy to identify the actual files so I can see how much they shrink after the REORG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The digits in the file name (i.e. `00003` = 3) correspond to the `TABLEID` column from `SYSCAT.TABLES`.  Please note that `TABLEID` is unique only within a single tablespace, so you need to know what tablespace's container path you are looking at to make this correlation.

All table data is stored in the `.DAT` file.

All index data (for all indexes) is stored in the `.INX` file, regardless of how many indexes there are.  (Note that it appears you have a typo in the filename SQL00003.IN1 above, this should be SQL00003.INX)

If your table has LOBs, then there will be 2 additional files with the same `SQLxxxxx` name:  a `.LBA` and a `.LB` file.

Comment: Thanks. Any idea what the .IN1 files are? The docs here said they were temporary reorg files: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.perf.doc/doc/c0024781.html .   But I have several that are persistent and get updated when I RUNSTATS or REORG my table.

Comment: And just to be clear, no typo there. There are .IN1 files in my tablespace directory. Based on the TABLEID scheme, some tables seem to have IN1 files, and some have INX files. There are not both for any tableid, so I would guess  that the IN1 files are the 'same' as the INX files.